# How to chain Iterable without computing underlying iterators

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

If I had two iterators I could just write `iter1 ++ iter2` and iterators would not be computed until they are needed. Is there any way to chain `Iterable` instances in the same way?

I tried to use `iterable1 ++ iterable2` but it causes immediately calculating nested values just like they are added to some structure. Is it possible to avoid this extra calculations and creating extra data structures?

Comment: I actually think that's kind of the purpose of iterators in the first place :D So I'd use iterable1.iterator ++ iterable2.iterator to avoid computation.

Comment: well, that is the backup plan

Comment: If you already have `Iterable`, than you've already calculated your nested values. It's not the chaining that is causing the caculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `Iterable` is just an interface that can be implemented by anything that can be iterated over. So when you have an `Iterable[Int]` that can be either a lazy or a strict collection, there's no way to know.

```
scala> val iterable1: Iterable[Int] = List(1,2,3)
iterable1: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> iterable1 ++ iterable1
res2: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)

scala> val iterable2: Iterable[Int] = List(1,2,3).view
iterable2: Iterable[Int] = SeqView(...)

scala> iterable2 ++ iterable2
res3: Iterable[Int] = SeqViewA(...)
```

Comment: So, I should basically use `iterable.view` to get desired behaviour?

Comment: @ayvango Yes, I think so. Or `iterable.iterator`. Documentation says that "all views for iterable collections are defined by re-interpreting the iterator method".

Answer (score 0):

You can code a simple chain-iterable that is a lazy concatenation of Iterable:

```
case class Chain[A](iter: Iterable[A]*) extends Iterable[A]{
  def iterator: Iterator[A] = iter.map(_.iterator).foldLeft(Iterator.empty: Iterator[A])(_++_)
}

Chain(List(1,2,3), 10 to 15, Vector(42,13))
```